# Recursive self joins

Tags: mysql, join, select, foreign-key

I have a `comments` table, which can be simplified down to this:

```
comments
=======
id
user_id
text
parent_id
```

where `parent_id` is nullable, but might be a key for its parent comment.

---

Now, how can I `select` all descendants of a specific comment?
The comments might be several levels down...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[Hierarchical queries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_query), as those recursive queries are known, are now [supported in MySQL 8](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html).

## Old Answer

Alternatively, you can find a dynamic (and thus, potentially dangerous) trick here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8104187/mysql-hierarchical-queries

You can also find a discussion on how to store hierarchical data with other models than with an **Adjacency List** (i.e. the *Parent* column) here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192220/what-is-the-most-efficient-elegant-way-to-parse-a-flat-table-into-a-tree/

Good luck!

Comment: I wonder how that solution in your second link can be dangerous.  Could you explain it?  Otherwise, welcome to the site!

Comment: @dezso: Quoth the crafter of the query himself, Quassnoi "_*It's not upgrade-safe* because MySQL does not clearly define session variable behaviour. However, it's the only way to deal with adjacency lists in a timely fashion in-query_." Dangerous might have been too strong a word (_potentially unstable_?) but I prefer to err on the side of caution (plus, I'm more knowledgeable in Oracle than MySQL, so I wanted to be extra precautious). Thanks for the welcome, by the way! I have been a long-time lurker to the SE network, and I decided it was time to pay back a bit.

Comment: The WITH [RECURSIVE] syntax is now supported from mysql 8.0.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html

Answer (score 7):

This table design is a SQL antipattern "Naive trees" as described by Bill Karwin (staring from slide 48 in his [SQL Antipatterns Strike Back](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/sql-antipatterns-strike-back) presentation). The problem with this design specifically is the difficulty with getting all descendants (or parents) of a node. Since you are using MySQL you can't use common table expressions (the WITH statement and it's RECURSIVE modifier) present in other RDBMSes.

What you're left with is:

- use an alternate implementation of hierarchical data structure (answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/935098/database-structure-for-tree-data-structure) might be a good reference on this)
- build self join queries with a depth limit. For depth = 5 you could use something in the lines of:

  ```
  SELECT *
  FROM comments AS c1
    JOIN comments AS c2 ON (c2.parent_id = c1.id)
    JOIN comments AS c3 ON (c3.parent_id = c2.id)
    JOIN comments AS c4 ON (c4.parent_id = c3.id)
    JOIN comments AS c5 ON (c5.parent_id = c4.id)
  ```
- use a RDBMS which supports WITH RECURSIVE (although this most likely is not an option for most people)

Comment: I disagree with Bill Karwin here. The adjacency model is **not** an anti-pattern. With a modern DBMS that supports recursive queries (Oracle has supported this for over 20 years) such a model is very efficient to retrieve *and* update.

Answer (score 5):

MySQL does not support recursive queries such as the one you need.

What I did a while back was write Stored Procedures that provide the model for doing so.

Rather than reinvent the wheel, I will give you the links to my past posts on this:

- `Oct 24, 2011` : [Find highest level of a hierarchical field: with vs without CTEs](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7147/find-highest-level-of-a-hierarchical-field-with-vs-without-ctes/7161#7161)
- `Dec 10, 2012` : [MySQL: Tree-Hierarchical query](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30021/mysql-tree-hierarchical-query/30114#30114)
- `Apr 12, 2013` : [Recursive query in mysql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39841/recursive-query-in-mysql/39863#39863)

In short, the Stored Procedures I made do preorder tree traversal using queue processing

- `GetParentIDByID`
- `GetAncestry`
- `GetFamilyTree`

## Parent to All Children (like GetFamilyTree Stored Procedure)

- STEP01) Start with a `parent_id` in a queue
- STEP02) Dequeue the next `parent_id` as the current
- STEP03) Enqueue all the `id` values that have the current `parent_id`
- STEP04) Print or Collect the Comment
- STEP05) If the queue is not empty, goto `STEP02`
- STEP06) You are done !!!

## Child to all Parent (like GetAncestry Stored Procedure)

- STEP01) Start with an `id` in a queue
- STEP02) Dequeue the next `id` as the current
- STEP03) Enqueue the `parent_id` value of the current `id`
- STEP04) Print or Collect the Comment
- STEP05) If the queue is not empty, goto `STEP02`
- STEP06) You are done !!!

Please look over the Stored Procedures in my other posts to see the implementation.

## Give it a Try !!!

Comment: recursive queries are now supported in MySQL 8 https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT  group_concat(@id :=
        (
        SELECT  id
        FROM    comments
        WHERE   parent_id = @id
        )) AS comment
FROM    (
        SELECT  @id := 1
        ) vars
STRAIGHT_JOIN
        comments
WHERE   @id IS NOT NULL
```

[fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3f8fd/9)